# Difference between scaling and squeezing

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

What is the difference between a [scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaling_(geometry)) and [squeeze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_mapping) transformation?

In what extent similar results may be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

- Scaling is defined in arbitrary dimensions, squeezing only in 2D.
- In 2D the scaling matrices are
  $$\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a & 0\\ 0 & b\end{pmatrix} \middle| a,b\in\mathbb R\right\}$$
  The squezzing matrices are
  $$\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a & 0\\ 0 & \frac 1 a\end{pmatrix}\middle| a\in\mathbb R \backslash\{0\}\right\}$$ 
  due to preservation of Euclidean area.